# Post Json data from ReactJs Frontend to Flask Backend with axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I managed to get data from Flask to ReactJs Frontend, but I haven't managed to send data from ReactJs to Flask API.

I'm uploading a file and storing it in Firebase. That works fine. But I want to send the downloadURL back to Flask API after it is stored.

Here's what I tried to do in the Frontend.

```
const FileUpload = ({}) => {
    var downloadLink;
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const formHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      uploadFiles(file);
      const postPath = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
            'path': downloadLink
        }).then(response => console.log(response));
    }
    postPath();
    };
```

That's what I'm doing to ensure that I send the data to API after the upload. So I'm calling `postPath()` after `uploadFiles(file)`.

And in server.py (Flask API) I'm doing the following to get the Json data.

```
@app.route('/filePath', methods=['POST'])
def get_path():
    return (request.get_json())
```

**NOTE** in the same server.py I have another route as well with a corresponding function. I don't know if it's relevant or not but here it is.

```
@app.route("/details")
def details():
    data = person(r'path').get_data()
    return {"name": data.get('name')
    }
```

I keep getting this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'preventDefault')

```
  16 |      uploadFiles(file);
  17 | 
  18 |      const postPath = (e) => {
> 19 |        e.preventDefault();
     | ^  20 |        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
  21 |            'path': downloadLink
  22 |        }).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the React code before it hits your Flask app: The `postPath` function is expecting to be passed an event, but you're calling it without any arguments: `postPath()`.

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')

In this case `e` is undefined, so you can't call `preventDefault` on it.

There's actually no need for `e.preventDefault()` inside `postPath`, `e.preventDefault()` is used in a form submission handler to prevent the default behavior (reloading the page) when a form is submitted. In your case you want to keep the first instance of `e.preventDefault()` but you can remove the second one.

You can actually remove the `postPath` function altogether, it's not really doing anything for you:

```
    const formHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      uploadFiles(file);
      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
        'path': downloadLink
      }).then(response => console.log(response));
    };
```

Comment: I thought preventDefault did the following: It prevents a link from following the URL so that the browser can't go another page. It prevents a submit button from submitting a form.
I was trying to prevent it from following a link but I guess that's not necessary since I'm only sending data and not redirecting